# ASP.NET CORE ModelのLocalizationについて

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

汎用性の高いDataannotations（例えばEmailAddress）を利用する場合に、同じResoruceファイルを指定するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
現在はこのようになっております。

```
// Resources\ViewModels\LoginViewModel.ja-JP.resx
// Resources\ViewModels\AccountEditViewModel.ja-JP.resx
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
名前  　　　　　| 値
EmailAddress　 | Eメールアドレス
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――


// LoginViewModel.cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")] //同じなので一つのResourceを参照したい
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    ....
}

// AccountEditViewModel.cs
public class AccountEditViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]  //同じなので一つのResourceを参照したい
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisplayAttribute.ResourceType`に共通のリソース型を指定すればよいと思います。

```
[Display(Name="EmailAddress", ResourceType=typeof(CommonResources))]
```